# Methods of working with threads in Google Test

Tags: c++, googletest

What are the methods of working with threads in Google Test? Compare thread, check deadlock, correct thread termination, thread safety?

Comment: You can edit your own post without having to write a comment.

Comment: What specifically are you trying to achieve? What have you already tried? What is it that you cannot do with standard thread functions and Google Test assertions?

Comment: Just learn thread testing methods

Comment: `EXPECT_NE(0, pthread_equal(t1, t2))`?

Comment: How to close a question?

Comment: @Daniel If you have found an answer to your question, you can answer your own question and mark the answer as accepted.